# Adding state to a nom parser

Tags: rust, state, nom

I wrote a parser in nom that is completely stateless, now I need to wrap it in a few stateful layers.

I have a top-level parsing function named `alt_fn` that will provide me the next bit of parsed output as an enum variant, the details of which probably aren't important.

I have three things I need to do that involve state:

1) I need to conditionally perform a transformation on the output of `alt_fn` if there is a match in a non-mutable HashMap that is part of my `State` struct. This should basically be like a `map!` but as a method call on my struct. Something like this:

```
named!(alt_fn<AllTags> ,alt!(// snipped for brevity));

fn applyMath(self, i:AllTags)->AllTags { // snipped for brevity }

method!(apply_math<State, &[u8], AllTags>, mut self, call_m!(self.applyMath, call!(alt_fn)));
```

This currently gives me: `error: unexpected end of macro invocation` with `alt_fn` underlined.

2) I need to update the other fields of the state struct with the data I got from the input (such as computing checksums and updating timestamps, etc.), and then transform the output again with this new knowledge. This will probably look like the following:

```
fn updateState(mut self, i:AllTags) -> AllTags { // snipped for brevity }

method!(update_state<State, &[u8], AllTags>, mut self, call_m!(self.updateState, call_m!(self.applyMath)));
```

3) I need to call the method from part two repeatedly until all the input is used up:

`method!(pub parse<State,&[u8],Vec<AllTags>>, mut self, many1!(update_state));`

Unfortunately the `nom` docs are pretty limited, and I'm not great with macro syntax so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I know the answer -> I'm not sure what the question is, but I can explain a bit how macros work in `nom`. In functional languages you can have [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), where passing some arguments to a function creates a new function asking for the remaining arguments. Nom sees combinators as these functions, where the last argument is the input, so passing other arguments in partial application creates concrete parsers. So `tag("a")` is a function expecting `i`, and `tag(i, "a")` is an actual command to apply the parser.Hope I help

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do something complicated with `nom`, I normally write my own functions.

For example

```
named!(my_func<T>, <my_macros>);
```

is equivalent to

```
fn my_func(i: &[u8]) -> nom::IResult<T, &[u8]> {
    <my_macros>
}
```

with the proviso that you must pass `i` to the macro (see my comment).

Creating your own function means you can have any control flow you want in there, and it will play nice with `nom` as long as it takes a &[u8] and returns nom::IResult where the output &[u8] is the remaining unparsed raw input.

If you need some more info comment and I'll try to improve my answer!

Comment: I'd go ahead and move your comment into your answer — comments are ephemeral, answers less so.